# How to delete a specific NSUserActivity search index?

Tags: ios, corespotlight, nsuseractivity

I use `NSUserActivity` to index a user activity for searching. I found a solution to delete a specific `NSUserActivity`, assign a `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` with `relatedUniqueIdentifier` to `NSUserActivity`:

```
let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeContact as String)
attributeSet.relatedUniqueIdentifier = objectId

let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: Employee.domainIdentifier)
activity.title = name
activity.userInfo = userActivityUserInfo
activity.keywords = [email, department]
activity.contentAttributeSet = attributeSet
```

And delete it use

```
[[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex] 
deleteSearchableItemsWithIdentifiers: objectId completionHandler:^(NSError *deletionError) {  
        if (deletionError) {  
            NSLog(@"Could not delete items from the search index with error %@", deletionError);  
        }  
    }];
```

I don't know if it is a right solution or not. Do you have a better solution to delete a specific `NSUserActivity` search index?

Comment: U can try `deleteSearchableItemsWithIdentifiers` or `deleteSearchableItemsWithDomainIdentifiers` then readd?

Comment: @Tj3n Oh, that is my current solution, one vote up for you. Sorry because I miss delete method in code. I will edit above code. My question is, it has other solutions to delete use NSUserActivity method, instead of linking NSUserActivity to a CSSearchableItemAttributeSet and delete use Core Spotlight medthod?

Comment: From my knowledge then no :/ I always have to use those code when i want to delete some searchable item

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 12, there are 2 methods to delete `NSUserActivity`

```
class func deleteAllSavedUserActivities(completionHandler: () -> Void)

class func deleteSavedUserActivities(withPersistentIdentifiers: [NSUserActivityPersistentIdentifier], completionHandler: () -> Void)
```

The docs note "Deletes all user activities stored by Core Spotlight or donated as Siri shortcuts."

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuseractivity