# How to delete group of NSUserActivity according to activityType

Tags: ios, corespotlight, nsuseractivity

I created bunch of `NSUserActivity` with different `activityType` as [documentation advices with reverse dns format](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserActivity_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserActivity/initWithActivityType:). Here is example of some `activityType`: `com.myCompany.myEditor.editing`. Now I want to delete all activities with this `activityType`, but I need to keep other activities with different `activityType`.

I know I can delete Spotlight indexing with methods:

```
- deleteAllSearchableItemsWithCompletionHandler:
- deleteSearchableItemsWithDomainIdentifiers:completionHandler:
- deleteSearchableItemsWithIdentifiers:completionHandler:
```

But...
I don't want to delete all userActivities.
Neither I can delete with `domainIdentifier`. `NSUserActivity` and `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` doesn't have property `domainIdentifier`.
I don't want to delete it one by one according to `relatedUniqueIdentifier` of `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` as noted in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647405/how-to-delete-a-specific-nsuseractivity-search-index).

How do I delete group of `NSUserActivity` according to `activityType`?

Comment: You can't.  Give the ones you want to be able to delete a domain identifier so you can delete them based on that

Comment: How do I do that? NSUserActivity doesn't have property `domainIdentifier`.

Comment: You create a `CSSearchableItem` with the domain identifier and the `uniqueIdentifier` equal to the `relatedUniqueIdentifier` on the user activity, then index the searchable item.

Comment: Do I have to create both `NSUserActivity` and `CSSearchableItem` with same identifier or is it enough to create just `CSSearchableItem`?

Comment: If you want to support handoff or have your objects added to the public search index then you should create both.  If you only care about adding things to the private on-device search index then you should only need the searchable item

Comment: Thanks :) If you create answer with pasted these comments I mark it as accepted.